# Program that reads file and writes new info

Tags: c#, file

So basically i have this text data file that contains Basketball player names and heights, i.e. "Tom is 6 ft" . From this text file with the basketball players names and heights I am trying to write a code that runs through each line of the text data file and separate the numbers from the strings, and find that if a player is greater than 6 ft then that player has made it to the team and send that player to another text file called made it. Know that the outcome has been explained I am having trouble trying to create code to be able separate the number from the string and recognise that a player if a player is 6 ft or over and put that player into a new text data file.

Here is the text data file containing the names and heights needed for the program: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10qLuyOzrV2EhFsQ9g4-28rLGIlLFGoDt/view?usp=sharing

Right now I have managed to create a program that reads the text data file and writes another text data file while also displaying line by line all the information in the text file on the console.

This is the code I have right now:

```
using System;

namespace basketball
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // This section shows how to read a file called Sample.txt stored in the Debug folder of the program folder 
        string fileName = @"Sample.TXT";
        Console.WriteLine("The contents of the file {0} is:", fileName);

        string[] dataFromFile = new string[100];
        int index = 0;

        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
        using (streamReader)
        {
            string fileContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            dataFromFile[index] = fileContents;

            Console.WriteLine(dataFromFile[index]);
            index++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Now Line By Line:");
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
        using (reader)
        {
            int lineNumber = 0;
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                lineNumber++;
                Console.WriteLine("Line {0}: {1}", lineNumber, line);
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        // This section shows how to write a file called madeit.txt stored in the console programs debug folder 

        string fileName2 = @"madeit.txt";
        System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName2);
        using (streamWriter)
        {
            for (int number = 1; number <= 20; number++)
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("This is line number : " + number);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("File is written!");

    }
}
}
```

This is currently what the console output looks like, here is a link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13_WKzfVriXlnfRcaqaPWbNFkc4Xix5z2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post the text file together with your question. The links in your question require permission to access them.

Comment: @preciousbetine should work now sorry

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a regular expression. Please see this example:

```
    List<string> players = new List<string> {
        @"Grady is 6'1"" ft",
        @"Robert is 5'10"" ft",
        @"Riley is 7 ft",
        @"Sam is 4'9"" ft",
        @"Greg is 6 ft",
        @"Raheem is 6'3"" ft",
        @"Connor is 5'11"" ft"
    };
    const string pattern = @"(.+) is (\d+)('\d+"")? ft";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    foreach (var player in players)
    {
        var match = regex.Match(player);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            bool sixFeetOrTaller = false;
            var name = match.Groups[1].Value;
            var inchesStr = match.Groups[2].Value;
            int inches;
            if (int.TryParse(inchesStr, out inches))
            {
                if (inches >= 6)
                {
                    sixFeetOrTaller = true;
                }
            }
            if (sixFeetOrTaller)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name + " made it to the team!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name + " did not make it to the team");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse line " + player);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Grady made it to the team!
Robert did not make it to the team
Riley made it to the team!
Sam did not make it to the team
Greg made it to the team!
Raheem made it to the team!
Connor did not make it to the team
```